# Magento 2.3.4l: When installing PHP SDK I find "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, installation, composer

I'm attempting to install `walmart-partner-api-sdk-php` from github using composer. Below is what I see on running the command to install. Any advice as to how to fix this is appreciated.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for fillup/walmart-partner-api-sdk-php ^1.0.9 -> sati                  sfiable by fillup/walmart-partner-api-sdk-php[1.0.9].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.5
    - fillup/walmart-partner-api-sdk-php 1.0.9 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^5.3.1                   -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 6.5.5].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.2, 6.5.5].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.3, 6.5.5].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.4, 6.5.5].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.5.5) -> satisfiabl                  e by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```